# array with 1 element causing error in for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm using the array length as the test condition in my for loop. But if there is only one element in the array, I receive an 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
string templateList;
string[] template;

string sizeList;
string[] size;

templateList = textBox1.Text;
template = templateList.Split(',');

sizeList = textBox2.Text;            
size = sizeList.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i <= template.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size.Length; j++)
    {
         //do something with template[i] and size[j]
    }
}
```

the values are coming from a textBox, the user may only enter one value. In which case it would only need to run once.

Comment: You would probably be better served using [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). Index math is really a waste of time in C#.

Answer (score 5):

Array is `zero-based` index, i.e first element has zero index. template[0] points first element. When you have only one element `template[1] will refer to second element` which is not present and you will probably get `out of index` exception.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= template.Length; i++)
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < template.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= template.Length; i++)
```

...on the last iteration `i` will equal `template.Length`.  `template[template.Length]` will always result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.  Since the last element of `template` actually has index `template.Length - 1`, you should instead use...

```
for (int i = 0; i < template.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Count start from zero, you have to change your first for statement into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < template.Length; i++) {....}
```